# Преобразовать "yyyy.mm.dd" в "yyyy-mm-dd"

Tags: c#

Попытался сделать вот так, но что-то ошибку выдает. Видел в интернете много примеров где с помощью метода `ToString()` преобразовывают дату, но мне нужно чтобы результат был в `DateTime` типе.

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015.05.05", "MM-dd-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Какую ошибку? Чтобы получить правильный ответ в максимально сжатые сроки, представляйте всю имеющуюся у Вас информацию.

Comment: Дополнительные сведения: Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете `ParseExact`, вторым параметром там идёт строка, которая определяет формат строки первой. Т.е. в Вашем случае вторым аргументом должен быть: `"yyyy.dd.MM"`.

Если Вам нужна строка, в приведённом выше формате, то для этого нужно использовать `ToString`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2015.05.05", "yyyy.dd.MM", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var str = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");//05-05-2015
//И обратное преобразование
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str , "MM-dd-yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Что касается:

> мне нужно чтобы результат был в DateTime типе

`DateTime` не имеет никакого формата, это класс для хранения даты. Формат присущ строковому представлению, из которого может быть создан `DateTime` или в который он может быть преобразован.

Comment: Как преобразовать var str = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");//05-05-2015 это в DateTime

Comment: @Radzhab, обновил код.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующий код

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(2015.05.05, "yyyy.mm.dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateFormate = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```